# How to get event.target and event.currentTarget in a webComponent (within a shadow root)

Tags: event-handling, web-component, shadow-dom

I tried to use the target object and the current target object of an event which occurs in one of my webComponents.
It seems that these methods aren't reachable within a shadow root.
Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`event.composedPath()` returns an Array of all elements/Nodes the Event passed

so the `target` you are after is in: `event.composedPath()[0]`

unless there are `mode:closed` shadowRoots in between

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath

> The composedPath() method of the Event interface returns the event’s
>   path which is an array of the objects on which listeners will be
>   invoked. This does not include nodes in shadow trees if the shadow
>   root was created with its ShadowRoot.mode closed.`

On Chrome/new Edge you can also use `event.path`